# Vue 3 Vite loading Vuetify/Element plus components in Root not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying to load vuetify or element plus components directly into #app.
It only works if I import all components, which of course means a huge file.
If I do manual or automatic import then I get :

```
Failed to resolve component:
```

I'm probably missing something in Vite but I can't figure it out.

If I load demo.vue then it works fine.

```
//Main.js 
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
app.component('demo', Demo);
app.mount('#app');

//demo.vue
<el-collapse v-model="activeName" accordion>
<el-collapse-item :title="test" name="1">
  <div>
    AAA
  </div>
  <div>
    AAA
  </div>
</el-collapse-item>
  </el-collapse>
```

If I load the contents of demo.vue in root #conatiner then error, but if I load all components then it works.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
const app = createApp({
mounted() {
console.log('The app is working')
}
});

const app2 = createApp(App) 
app2.mount('#container')
```

My vite-config

```
     import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { ElementPlusResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'
import path from 'path'
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  //base: '/dist/',
 
  plugins: [
    vue({
     
    }), AutoImport({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    }),


  ], resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler',
    },
  }, build: {
    
    outDir: '../wwwroot/distback',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        front: fileURLToPath(new URL('./qasar/index.html', import.meta.url)),
       
       
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }
    }
  },
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue',
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 5000,
  },
})
```

Comment: if you are not globally registering all components then you must import them individually where ever you are using them.
`import { VButton }  from 'vuetify/components`

Comment: That's the -problem, once I import them manually like your example, it stops working. It will only work if I mount demo.vue

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify and element Plus seems to have a conflict. I use Elemet Plus carousel and other components but it started to not work when I installed vuetify. I tried removing vuetify and then it work again.